# insert value textbox into mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have problems inserting a textboxvalue into a mysql database - there's no errormessage and no inserting. What am I doing wrong

```
 private void RegisterCustomer()
    {
        string firstname = txtfirstname.ToString();

        OdbcConnection conn;
        conn = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jConnString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string sql = "insert into klant (firstname) values (@firstname)";
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstname", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = firstname;
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Check.Text += ex.ToString() + sql;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            Check.Text += "OK";
        }
    }
```

Comment: First 2 things I'd check:  When you run it in the debugger, which of the try/catch/finally blocks does it do?  When you look at the SQL logs, what statement is it trying to run?

Comment: Is txtfirstname a text box control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters.aspx

When CommandType is set to Text, the .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC does not support passing named parameters to an SQL statement or to a stored procedure called by an OdbcCommand. In either of these cases, use the question mark (?) placeholder.

So your query should be:

`string sql = "insert into klant (firstname) values (?)"`

If you have multiple parameters, they are set in the order you add them.

In addition, I think the line

`string firstname = txtfirstname.ToString();`

should read

`string firstname = txtfirstname.Text();`

But that is not what is causing your immediate problem.

Comment: string sql = "insert into klant (firstname) values (?)" works!                                                            but string firstname = txtfirstname.Text(); or string firstname = txtfirstname.Value.ToString(); still gives me System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText inserted into my database

Comment: what worrks is string firstname = txtfirstname.Value

Answer (score 0):

```
"insert into klant values (firstname) values (@firstname)"
```

I think the right query would be:

```
"insert into klant values (@firstname)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
string sql = "insert into klant values (firstname) values (@firstname)";
```

Is specifying `values` twice. It should be in the form:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
[INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
{VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
[ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  col_name=expr
    [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

So remove the extra `values` and you should be good.

Comment: little mistake , fixed it , but thats not it

Answer (score 0):

You have values twice.  I've never seen it that way.  You INSERT INTO table (columm_names...) VALUES (value1, 'value2',...)

edit:  maybe you should try straight text and eliminate the box to see if it enters.  At least you'll know where to look.

edit:  I'd also echo my firstname variable to see what it has.

Comment: little mistake , fixed it , but thats not it

Answer (score -1):

More accurately, it should be:

```
insert into klant (firstname) values (@firstname)
```