# Trying to get user inputted text in C# windows form app over to MySQL database, nothing but speedbumps

Tags: c#, mysql, database, textbox

I'll start off by saying I'm a noob with all of this, I have yet to see people flame others on this site but would love not to be the first :P

As the title suggests I'm having a difficult time getting it to work and would very much appreciate any/all help.

And I did search google for quite sometime, came across posts on here before with others who had errors, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306311/errors-trying-to-insert-into-mysql-database) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228396/insert-value-textbox-into-mysql-database).  Played around with the code, tried to find the errors and couldn't.

The program has coding for an image to base64 conversion that has no errors, but would like to incorporate the code into the database as well at some point..

This is what I have, (Probably the one farthest from where I need to be though..):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Microsoft.Data.Odbc;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace BaseEncoder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            byte[] imageBytes = null;

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:/Users/m29582/Desktop/capture1.jpeg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            //C:\Data\Kinect App\KinectApp\bin\Debug\capture0.jpeg

            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);
            try
            {
                long size = reader.BaseStream.Length;
                imageBytes = new byte[size];
                for (long i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    imageBytes[i] = reader.ReadByte();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }
            string imageString = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:/Users/m29582/Desktop/zcapture1.txt");
            label1.Text = "Enter First Name:";
            label2.Text = "Enter Last Name:";
            label3.Text = "Enter Date of Birth, ex.(1990):";
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string firstname = textBox1.Text;
            string lastname = textBox2.Text;
            string dob = textBox3.Text;
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:/Users/m29582/Desktop/zcapture1.txt");
            MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=kinect; Uid=root; Pwd=***;");
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            cn.Open();
            ds = new DataSet();
            da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Insert into kinect (Number, First Name, Last Name, DOB) values (null, @firstname, @lastname, @dob)", cn);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            da.Update(ds);
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
            cn.Close();
        }
```

The code before button1_Clicked I just included because, the problems with the button1_clicked.  I have tried so many different examples, tried to play around with others code that were having a hard time as well, tried:

```
da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Insert into kinect (Number, First Name, Last Name, DOB) values (null, " + @firstname + "," + @lastname + "," + @dob + ")", cn);
```

Along with a few other variations with "?" as well.  I don't know if I need to use the MySQL, ODBC or SQL, (if it even matters..), because I have almost no experience with this...  So sorry to give such a lengthy explanation, to sum it up again, I would love some help trying to get the text inputs from the textboxes to be stored into the corresponding columns in the database if possible.

As a side-note, I would also love a little help trying to incorporate the base64 coded picture into the database as well if you know something off the top of your head.  I will mark answers, +rep, thank etc everyone who helps unlike the ingrates who leech off your time and don't say/do anything but use your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this subject, but judging by [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter.html#connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter-ctor) you can only pass a `SELECT` query to the `MySqlDataAdapter` constructor, not an `INSERT` one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give that a try!  Once I Get more rep I'll mark as helpful as well